# Usability of this Observable class

Tags: swift

I created an Observable class that allows me to subscribe to a wrapped value. The implementation looks like this:

```
class Observable<ValueType> {
    typealias DidChangeHandler = (oldValue: ValueType?, newValue: ValueType) -> ()

    // MARK: Properties

    var value : ValueType {
        didSet {
            for (owner, handlers) in self._observers {
                for handler in handlers {
                    handler(oldValue: oldValue, newValue: value)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Initializers

    init(_ value: ValueType) {
        self.value = value
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func addObserverForOwner(owner: AnyObject, triggerImmediately: Bool, handler: DidChangeHandler) {
        if let index = self._indexOfOwner(owner) {
            // since the owner exists, add the handler to the existing array
            self._observers[index].handlers.append(handler)
        }
        else {
            // since the owner does not already exist, add a new tuple with the
            // owner and an array with the handler
            self._observers.append(owner: owner, handlers: [handler])
        }

        if (triggerImmediately) {
            handler(oldValue: nil, newValue: self.value)
        }
    }

    func removeObserversForOwner(owner: AnyObject) {
        if let index = self._indexOfOwner(owner) {
            self._observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Private Properties

    private var _observers: [(owner: AnyObject, handlers: [DidChangeHandler])] = []

    // MARK: Private Methods

    private func _indexOfOwner(owner: AnyObject) -> Int? {
        var index: Int = 0
        for (possibleOwner, handlers) in self._observers {
            if possibleOwner === owner {
                return index
            }
            index++
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This allows me to create a variable and observer it as follows:

```
var observableString = Observable<String>("String")

observableString.addObserverForOwner(self, triggerImmediately: false) {
    (oldValue, newValue) in
    // ...
}
```

I think this is most useful to use for properties on classes.

However, there are a few things that I don't like:

- Requires manually unobserving even if the owner is dealloced
- triggerImmediately seems kind of verbose
- oldValue has to be an optional because in the `triggerImmediately` case there is no old value

Mostly I am looking for any ideas on ways to improve the usability of this interface, but I am open to any ways to improve the code.

---

## Update 08/02/2014

I actually figured out a way to not require manually unobserving if the owner is deallocated. It isn't perfect, but it does work. Basically I created a `WeakWrapper` class that makes a weak reference to a wrapped value. This allows Observable to keep an array of weak references instead of strong references to observers. The reference will be set to `nil` when the observer is dealloced so I can clean them up the next time the observable is triggered. The negative part of it is that the handlers are not removed until the next time the observable is triggered.

To see the new code, including changes suggested by @nhgrif below, you can visit my [github repository](https://github.com/drewag/SwiftPlusPlus/blob/master/SwiftPlusPlus/Observable.swift).

Comment: Has there been an update to Swift that I don't know about?  Last I checked, there was no way to set access levels...

Comment: @nhgrif yes, access levels were added in beta 4

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, ObjC observers always need to remove themselves manually as well.  I can't think of a good workable solution for this problem really.

Comment: @nhgrif In Objective-C you can use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to setup [observers that remove themselves](https://github.com/drewag/property-bindings), but ya, I can't think of a way to do that with the current Swift features.

Comment: @nhgrif I actually did think of a way to have observers removed automatically. See my update.

Answer (score 4):

You worry about `triggerImmediately` being too verbose (which can be fixed), yet you have `addObserverForOwner` as the primary function name, and for me, this is the part that is a bit too verbose.

Since what we're doing with this is so similar to the existing KVO in Objective-C (which can also be used in Swift), we'd do well to make this look and feel like KVO.

The KVO method looks like this: `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`.  In KVO however, we don't get to pick our own handler.  We just have to implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.

Now, I'm not going to recommend a direct copy.  We can drop the `forKeyPath:` part of the first method.  The general consensus with KVO also seems to be that `context:` is relatively useless (it's a value you send when you start observing, and it is sent back to you in the call back method).  I also do like that you're suggesting the user can pick whatever method or function they want as the handler.

But, let's make some changes, shall we?

First of all, let's change our handler.  Instead of a method that takes an `oldValue` and a `newValue`, let's use a method that just takes a dictionary, shall we?

We're doing this, because we should change `triggerImmediately` to options, and provide an `enum` that lets users build a bitmask for their options.  In KVO, we have the following options:

- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`
- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld`
- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial`
- `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior`

The first two are self explanatory.

`NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial` is a flag that say the handler block should be called before the `addObserver` method is finished--we send the current value of the observable to the handler block as a "new" value.

`NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior` means the user wants to know about the values just before they're actually changed.  In the case of Swift, this means we'd fire in `willSet` with this option on (but we also still fire in `didSet`).

I'm not suggesting you use the `NSKeyValueObservingOption` enum.  I suggest you create your own enum.  As a minimum, include these options, but you may want to include others as well at some point in the future.  Maybe a `StopObservingAfterChange` option that automatically removes the observer after the first `didSet` for example.

But anyway, about our `handler`.  It should just take a dictionary argument as I stated earlier.  What values it contains will depend on the scenario and which bits are set in the options.

If the `new` bit is set, the dictionary will always hold the new value.  If the `old` bit is set, it will hold the old value in every situation it can (i.e. not when the `initial` bit is set and we fire before the `addObserver` method returns).

If the `prior` bit is set, when we call the handler from `willSet`, we include another key: `"prior"` which holds a boolean value of `true`.  I guess you could realistically include this key every time just set it to `false` in every other scenario.

Anyways, changing the add observer method to:

```
addObserver(observer:AnyObject, options:ObservableOptions, handler:DidChangeHandler);
```

Means that you can always add options in the future without screwing up any of the existing uses.  And changing the handler to taking a dictionary means we throw all the values we want to send to the handler into the dictionary, and not only is the handler flexible for different current use cases, it is also flexible for all future use cases.

As a final note, I might include constant values to use as the keys to the "change" dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I wholeheartedly agree with your idea about using a bitmask instead of triggerImmediately. However, I disagree about the idea of using a dictionary to report the values. Dictionaries are bad for discoverability and type safety. I think it may actually make sense to create an enum, struct, or class called something like `Change` that holds the various changes. Finally, I can't decided if the owner is considered the "observer" or the closure itself. Depending on the answer to that, I agree about changing the name to just `addObserver`

Comment: I'm actually a little confused about the `owner`/`observer` myself.  What role is it intending to play?  What does the `owner` "own" in your mind?

Comment: The owner is really just there for removing observers as I couldn't think of any other way to allow the removal of specific observers. The idea was that the "owner" owned the observer which was the closure, but it may make more sense to just consider the "owner" the "observer".

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback. You can see my updated Observable class on [github](https://github.com/drewag/SwiftPlusPlus/blob/master/SwiftPlusPlus/Observable.swift).